# Display SQLite data in Android tablelayout

Tags: java, android, sqlite, tablelayout

Im trying to retrieve data from SQLite database table and display as tablelayout in android. However it only display the title and the textview. What is wrong with the codes?

Graf.java

```
public class Graf extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper myDb;
TextView dt, water, inc;
TableLayout tableLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graf);
    myDb=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    dt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
    water=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.water);
    inc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.inc);
    tableLayout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);



    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    final String date=getDate();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    BuildTable(date);




}

private void BuildTable(String date){

    Cursor c=myDb.readEntry(date);

    int rows=c.getCount();
    int cols=c.getColumnCount();

    c.moveToFirst();

    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        for (int j=0;j<cols;j++){
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setTextSize(18);
            tv.setPadding(0,5,0,5);

            tv.setText(c.getString(j));

            row.addView(tv);
        }

        c.moveToNext();

        tableLayout.addView(row);
    }


}





/*public void getData(){

    buttonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
                if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                    showMessage("Ralat", "Tiada Rekod.");
                }

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (res.moveToNext()) {
                    buffer.append("Tarikh       : " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Air Diminum  : " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Pencapaian   : " + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
                    showMessage("Laporan", buffer.toString());
                }


        }
    });
}

public void showMessage(String title, String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}*/



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_graf, menu);
    return true;
}

private String getDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

activity_graf.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.Graf">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="LAPORAN MINGGUAN ANDA"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tarikh" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/water"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Penambahan Air" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Peningkatan Peratus" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

DatabaseHelper myDb;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HU.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "User_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "GENDER";
public static final String COL_5 = "WEIGHT";
public static final String COL_6 = "HEIGHT";
public static final String COL_7 = "ACTIVENESS";
public static final String COL_8 = "TARGET";

public static final String TABLE2_NAME = "Drink_Table";
public static final String COL2_1 = "DRINK_ID";
public static final String COL2_2 = "DATE";
public static final String COL2_3 = "AMOUNT";
public static final String COL2_4 = "PERCENT";
public static final String COL2_5 = "ID";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, GENDER TEXT, WEIGHT DOUBLE, HEIGHT DOUBLE, ACTIVENESS INTEGER, TARGET DOUBLE)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE2_NAME + " (DRINK_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, DATE DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, AMOUNT DOUBLE, PERCENT DOUBLE, ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID))");
    db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE3_NAME+" (Entry_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , ID INTEGER, DATE DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, TOTALAMOUNT DOUBLE, TOTAL PERC DOUBLE, FOREIGN KEY(DATE) REFERENCES "+TABLE2_NAME+"(DATE), FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES "+TABLE_NAME+"(ID))");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String name, String gender, String weight, String height, String activeness, String target) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, gender);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, weight);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, height);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, activeness);
    contentValues.put(COL_8, target);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

public boolean updateData(String id, String name, String gender, String weight, String height, String activeness, String target) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, gender);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, weight);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, height);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, activeness);
    contentValues.put(COL_8, target);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[]{id});
    return true;
}

public boolean addWater(String date, String id, double amount) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    double target = getTargetu(id);
    contentValues.put(COL2_2, date);
    contentValues.put(COL2_3, amount);
    contentValues.put(COL2_4, (amount / target) * 100);
    contentValues.put(COL2_5, id);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE2_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

 public Cursor readEntry(String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = ("SELECT DATE, AMOUNT, PERCENT FROM "+TABLE2_NAME+"WHERE DATE= ?");
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE2_NAME,new String[]{COL2_2,COL2_3,COL2_4},COL2_2+"=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(date)}, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;

}

private String getDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with picking wrong layout params. Should be:

```
row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Table layout requires table Layout params.

Comment: Ive tried but there is no changes. The table does not appear